# Trying to git push three large text files to Github using git lfs

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

After installing `git lfs` v2.3.4 for Windows, and enabling my repo to use `lfs` on all my `.txt` extension files using the following.

1. `git lfs track "*.txt"`
2. `git add .gitattributes`
3. Inside my .gitattributes, `*.txt filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text`

When I try to `git add .`, `git commit -m "initial commit"`, then finally `git push` I get the following error:

```
Remote "origin" does not support the LFS locking API. Consider disabling it with:
  $ git config lfs.https://github.com/0xdec0de5/super_kali_wordlist.git/info/lfs.locksverify false
```

After running the following, `git config lfs.locksverify false`

I get the following error:

```
batch response: Git credentials for https://github.com/0xdec0de5/super_kali_wordlist.git not found.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/0xdec0de5/super_kali_wordlist.git'
```

Any help to resolve the error would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on git via the command window. Instead I installed [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/).

After watching [this](https://youtu.be/uLR1RNqJ1Mw?t=1m37s) I tried Github Desktop and was successful pushing my LFS files.

Unfortunately I was unable to find a solution using git from the command window.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using those, use " git init" in working folder, then "git add remote origin (your origin address)", after that "git add . "  then commit by using "git commit -m (message with quotes)" like "message" then push to your repository by "git push origin master"